# The code Im using to split numpy ndarray is not giving the desired results

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, encryption

I am reading image file and slicing it into four parts. I want to store those 4 parts separately so that I can use work on them. But I don't want them to store as image file. I want them to be stored as numpy array in memory and perform the function. Here is the code where I Split the Image array. I can print the array but I am unable to see that array displayed as image again.

```
shuImg = np.reshape(oriImg, (oriImg.shape[0] * oriImg.shape[1], oriImg.shape[2]))

#now shuffle
np.random.shuffle(shuImg)
cv2.imshow("Image with shuffled pixels",rdmImg)
cv2.waitKey()
arr1 = rdmImg
n=4
for i in range(1,n):

    b[i] = np.split(arr1, 4)

for i in range(1,n):
    print("split array", b)
    cv2.imshow("The splitted image is ",b)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: print `b.shape` before imshow. what is it? where is `b` defined? please present a [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Tried this as well but it shows the error: 
Overload resolution failed:
>  - mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::cuda::GpuMat> for argument 'mat'
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'

Comment: using b[i] array which is initialized in first for loop
b[i] = np.split(arr1, 4)

Comment: I am asking for the value of `b.shape`. you can get that before the error happens.

Comment: `b[i] =...` does not initialize an array or list; it assigns a value to an existing object.  Your `b.shape` error tells us - and you - that `b` was already created, and is not a numpy or list.  If you want help, provide all the relevant information.  Don't make us guess or assume things.